# Apache2 - Using mod_rewrite to proxy to another domain

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2.4

I'm running Apache 2.4 and using mod_rewrite to achieve the following - I need to proxy several different internal sites so that they appear to have been hosted on the same server. As an example, the way I'm looking to do this is to have URL's of the form `http://myserver/osnews`
which will proxy content from `www.osnews.com` and `http://myserver/slashdot` which will proxy content from `www.slashdot.org`. I have the following rewrite-rule defined in my apache conf file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/osnews(/?.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/osnews(.*) http://www.osnews.com$1 [P]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/slshdot(/?.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/osnews(.*) http://www.slashdot.org$1 [P]
```

The problem is that this breaks all the stylesheets and images from the proxied site. I think it's because the rewritten URL's are of the form     `http://myserver/story/28554/Russia_unveils_homegrown_PC_microprocessor_chips` instead of     `http://myserver/osnews/story/28554/Russia_unveils_homegrown_PC_microprocessor_chips`

On the contrary, if I try something like this, it works just fine (I don't have the site as part of the original url so `http://myserver` will just proxy to `http://www.osnews.com`):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myserver$ [NC]                                                          
RewriteRule ^ http://www.osnews.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

So, what I need direction on is how to preserve the URL `http://mysite/osnews/some-resource` after the proxying returns from `http://osnews.com/some-resource`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, I have got this working using mod_proxy instead of mod_rewrite. The configuration I used (within the VirtualHost context) is:

```
    ProxyPass /osnews.com/ http://www.osnews.com/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://www.osnews.com /osnews.com
    #LogLevel debug proxy_html:trace5
    <Location /osnews.com/>
        ProxyPassReverse /osnews.com/
        ProxyHTMLEnable On
        ProxyHTMLExtended On
        ProxyHTMLURLMap ^/ /osnews.com/ R
        ProxyHTMLURLMap ^/css/(.*) /osnews.com/css/$1 Rc
        ProxyHTMLURLMap ^/images/(.*) /osnews.com/images/$1 Rc
        RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
    </Location>
```

One thing to note is that if you're using apache2 on Ubuntu (Lubuntu 15.04 in my case), the config file for mod proxy_html is not provided by default. You need to create it and then enable it using `a2enmod proxy_html`. This article summarizes it well: http://ckdake.com/content/2008/reverse-proxying-with-apache-and-modproxyhtml.html.

There are still some issues I see where the ProxyHTMLExtended output-filter is not mapping URLS correctly. But I expect to get those ironed out eventually.